# Node.js / Mongoose - Error when trying to create document with Arrays in it, even though my code is the same as the instructor's

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, typeerror, mongoose-schema

**My mongoose schema is:**

```
const tourSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
...
images: [String],
...
startDates: [Date]
});
```

**My API create function is:**

```
exports.createTour = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const newTour = await Tour.create(req.body);
    res.status(201).json({
      status: "success",
      data: {
        tour: newTour
      }
    });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).json({
      status: "fail",
      message: error
    });
  }
};
```

**Data input:**

```
{
    "name": "The Forest Hiker",
    ...
    "images": ["tour-1-1.jpg", "tour-1-2.jpg", "tour-1-3.jpg"],
    "startDates": ["2021-04-25,10:00", "2021-07-20,10:00", "2021-10-05,10:00"]
}
```

**Error:**

```
{
    "status": "fail",
    "message": {
        "errors": {
            "images": {
                "stringValue": "\"[]\"",
                "valueType": "string",
                "kind": "[undefined]",
                "value": "[]",
                "path": "images.1",
                "reason": {},
                "name": "CastError",
                "message": "Cast to [undefined] failed for value \"[]\" (type string) at path \"images.1\" because of \"TypeError\""
            },
            "startDates": {
                "stringValue": "\"[]\"",
                "valueType": "string",
                "kind": "[undefined]",
                "value": "[]",
                "path": "startDates.1",
                "reason": {},
                "name": "CastError",
                "message": "Cast to [undefined] failed for value \"[]\" (type string) at path \"startDates.1\" because of \"TypeError\""
            },
            "images.undefined": {
                "stringValue": "\"[\"tour-3-1.jpg\",\"tour-3-2.jpg\",\"tour-3-3.jpg\"]\"",
                "valueType": "string",
                "kind": "[undefined]",
                "value": "[\"tour-3-1.jpg\",\"tour-3-2.jpg\",\"tour-3-3.jpg\"]",
                "path": "images.undefined",
                "reason": {},
                "name": "CastError",
                "message": "Cast to [undefined] failed for value \"[\"tour-3-1.jpg\",\"tour-3-2.jpg\",\"tour-3-3.jpg\"]\" (type string) at path \"images.undefined\" because of \"TypeError\""
            },
            "startDates.undefined": {
                "stringValue": "\"[\"2022-01-05,10:00\",\"2022-02-12,10:00\",\"2023-01-06,10:00\"]\"",
                "valueType": "string",
                "kind": "[undefined]",
                "value": "[\"2022-01-05,10:00\",\"2022-02-12,10:00\",\"2023-01-06,10:00\"]",
                "path": "startDates.undefined",
                "reason": {},
                "name": "CastError",
                "message": "Cast to [undefined] failed for value \"[\"2022-01-05,10:00\",\"2022-02-12,10:00\",\"2023-01-06,10:00\"]\" (type string) at path \"startDates.undefined\" because of \"TypeError\""
            }
        },
        "_message": "Tour validation failed",
        "name": "ValidationError",
        "message": "Tour validation failed: images: Cast to [undefined] failed for value \"[]\" (type string) at path \"images.1\" because of \"TypeError\", startDates: Cast to [undefined] failed for value \"[]\" (type string) at path \"startDates.1\" because of \"TypeError\", images.undefined: Cast to [undefined] failed for value \"[\"tour-3-1.jpg\",\"tour-3-2.jpg\",\"tour-3-3.jpg\"]\" (type string) at path \"images.undefined\" because of \"TypeError\", startDates.undefined: Cast to [undefined] failed for value \"[\"2022-01-05,10:00\",\"2022-02-12,10:00\",\"2023-01-06,10:00\"]\" (type string) at path \"startDates.undefined\" because of \"TypeError\""
    }
}
```

**Software versions:**
    node v19.5.0
    mongoose v6.9.0
    mongodb (on Atlas Shared Cluster) v6.0.4

## **Notes**

I am connecting to the Atlas Shared Cluster. I have to use the mongoose v6.9.0 for this, v5.x.x threw a URI Parse error and I could not resolve that other than by updating mongoose. (Local connection had been OK, and also connecting to Cluster from the Mongo Shell had been OK.)

The places in which I use ellipses (...) in my code are completely identical to a code snippet in a course I am following on Udemy, and it works for the instructor and seemingly for everyone else.

## **My Thoughts**

I suspect something about the newer Mongoose release I am using, or some configuration setting, because my code is 100% identical to the one written by Jonas. I have spent now 2 hours trying to figure this out, to no avail. Finally, I decided to do a workaround.

---

## **MY WORKAROUND**

When I pass the arrays as strings, everything works fine, I just need to convert back every time I use them afterwards, which is not good for performance.Schema:

```
const tourSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
...
images: String,
...
startDates: String
});
```

API create function:

```
exports.createTour = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    req.body.images = req.body.images.toString();
    req.body.startDates = req.body.startDates.toString();
    const newTour = await Tour.create(req.body);
    res.status(201).json({
      status: "success",
      data: {
        tour: newTour
      }
    });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).json({
      status: "fail",
      message: error
    });
  }
};
```

**Any help or feedback is appreciated!**

---

**Edit / Addendum No. 1**

The req.body sent to the server is the following JSON object:

```
{
    "name": "The Snow Adventurer",
    "duration": 4,
    "maxGroupSize": 10,
    "difficulty": "difficult",
    "ratingsAverage": 4.5,
    "ratingsQuantity": 13,
    "price": 997,
    "summary": "Exciting adventure in the snow with snowboarding and skiing",
    "description": "Sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua, ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum!\nDolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur, exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit!",
    "imageCover": "tour-3-cover.jpg",
    "images": ["tour-3-1.jpg", "tour-3-2.jpg", "tour-3-3.jpg"],
    "startDates": ["2022-01-05,10:00", "2022-02-12,10:00", "2023-01-06,10:00"]
  }
```

The console.log(req.body) is the following - req.body logged directly before creation of new document, as seen below:

```
exports.createTour = async (req, res) => {
  try {

    console.log(req.body);

    console.log(req.body.images);
    console.log("The type of req.body.images is: ", typeof req.body.images);

    console.log(req.body.startDates);
    console.log(
      "The type of req.body.startDates is: ",
      typeof req.body.startDates
    );

    const newTour = await Tour.create(req.body);
    res.status(201).json({
      status: "success",
      data: {
        tour: newTour
      }
    });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).json({
      status: "fail",
      message: error
    });
  }
};
```

```
{
  name: 'The Snow Adventurer',
  duration: 4,
  maxGroupSize: 10,
  difficulty: 'difficult',
  ratingsAverage: 4.5,
  ratingsQuantity: 13,
  price: 997,
  summary: 'Exciting adventure in the snow with snowboarding and skiing',
  description: 'Sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua, ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum!\n' +
    'Dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur, exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit!',
  imageCover: 'tour-3-cover.jpg',
  images: [ 'tour-3-1.jpg', 'tour-3-2.jpg', 'tour-3-3.jpg' ],
  startDates: [ '2022-01-05,10:00', '2022-02-12,10:00', '2023-01-06,10:00' ]
}
```

As seen, interestingly, the req.body is showing that arrays are being passed to the Tour.create() method. Furthermore, I have made typeof logs of the passed arrays, which returned the following:

```
[ 'tour-3-1.jpg', 'tour-3-2.jpg', 'tour-3-3.jpg' ]
The type of req.body.images is:  object
[ '2022-01-05,10:00', '2022-02-12,10:00', '2023-01-06,10:00' ]
The type of req.body.startDates is:  object
```

This makes me certain that the fields are Array objects - deduced by inference that strings are a primitive type in JS and therefore the typeof cannot return object then.
Which makes the bug all the stranger.

---

**Edit / Addendum No. 2**

I get the same error when I load my data via a script in the terminal.

```
currentuser@Currentusers-MBP 4-natours % node dev-data/data/import-dev-data.js --import
mongodb+srv://kraftwerk:APEL0P6WIH7xTeYf@cluster0.9iia2xw.mongodb.net/natours?retryWrites=true&w=majority
Error: Tour validation failed: images: Cast to [undefined] failed for value "[]" (type string) at path "images.1" because of "TypeError", startDates: Cast to [undefined] failed for value "[]" (type string) at path "startDates.1" because of "TypeError", images.undefined: Cast to [undefined] failed for value "["tour-1-1.jpg__tour-1-2.jpg__tour-1-3.jpg"]" (type string) at path "images.undefined" because of "TypeError", startDates.undefined: Cast to [undefined] failed for value "["2021-04-25,10:00__2021-07-20,10:00__2021-10-05,10:00"]" (type string) at path "startDates.undefined" because of "TypeError"
    at ValidationError.inspect (/Users/currentuser/Documents/GitHub/node-course-2023/4-natours/node_modules/mongoose/lib/error/validation.js:50:26)
    at formatValue (node:internal/util/inspect:805:19)
    at inspect (node:internal/util/inspect:364:10)
    at formatWithOptionsInternal (node:internal/util/inspect:2291:40)
    at formatWithOptions (node:internal/util/inspect:2153:10)
    at console.value (node:internal/console/constructor:339:14)
    at console.log (node:internal/console/constructor:376:61)
    at importData (/Users/currentuser/Documents/GitHub/node-course-2023/4-natours/dev-data/data/import-dev-data.js:62:13)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  errors: {
    images: CastError: Cast to [undefined] failed for value "[]" (type string) at path "images.1" because of "TypeError"
        at SchemaArray.cast (/Users/currentuser/Documents/GitHub/node-course-2023/4-natours/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema/array.js:389:15)
        at SchemaType.applySetters (/Users/currentuser/Documents/GitHub/node-course-2023/4-natours/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:1201:12)
        at SchemaType.getDefault (/Users/currentuser/Documents/GitHub/node-course-2023/4-natours/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:1141:25)
        at applyDefaults (/Users/currentuser/Documents/GitHub/node-course-2023/4-natours/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/document/applyDefaults.js:99:24)
        at model.Document (/Users/currentuser/Documents/GitHub/node-course-2023/4-natours/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:158:7)
        at model.Model (/Users/currentuser/Documents/GitHub/node-course-2023/4-natours/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:122:12)
        at new model (/Users/currentuser/Documents/GitHub/node-course-2023/4-natours/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:5092:15)
        at /Users/currentuser/Documents/GitHub/node-course-2023/4-natours/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:3197:22
        at /Users/currentuser/Documents/GitHub/node-course-2023/4-natours/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:3232:7
        at Array.forEach (<anonymous>) {
      stringValue: '"[]"',
      messageFormat: undefined,
      kind: '[undefined]',
      value: '[]',
      path: 'images.1',
      reason: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
```

Also, my [Postman](https://ibb.co/M2nX9T1) seems to be configured correctly, i.e. I am sending data in **raw** / **JSON** (application/json) format.

Comment: Can you show the result of `console.log(req.body)`?

Comment: Your code looks fine, please show the `req.body`

Answer (score 0):

Do you use Postman to test your API? Your code seems working fine, the `Schema` and `req.body` is not a problem, and the only thing I think is you configure the Postman wrong way, so it send your request as a **string**, not an **array**. Make sure you set the content-type in Postman to JSON as seen this [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cG2og.jpg)

Comment: I have checked and unfortunately it is not a Postman configuration error, for two reasons. One, I have [Postman configured](https://ibb.co/M2nX9T1) just like the picture you sent. Two, I get the same CastErrors even when I load the data via a script in the terminal. I added this in Addendum 2.